# Setting alarm clock to be shown in Clock application

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, alarms

Is there way to set up alarm clock in my application - this means that when I use something like AlarmManager or else, my new alarm would be visible on my alarm list in stock Clock application. I read some tutorials and did some but none has managed to do what I've wanted.

I need this for API 8+

Comment: what specifically are you looking for? What have you tried? why did it not meet your expectations?

Comment: I added an example. Hopefully i explained it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to get your alarms to show up in the default Alarms overview? Short answer - no. The default Alarms / Clock application has its own private database and you can't access that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Did not that, so you save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

What specifically have you had trouble with? Have you examined how it's done in the official app? You can download the source tree and see how Google manage alarms in the AlarmClock app: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html